# Turn if in to switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

could I turn this into a switch statement ?

```
if (donation_euro.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            donation_euro.Text = "00.00";
        }
        if (donation_lui.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            donation_lui.Text = "00.00";
        }
        if (donation.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            donation.Text = "00.00";
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you associate the string with a float, and then parse the float as a string when necessary. e.g. `float donationEuro = 0.0F`, and then `donation_euro.Text = ""+donationEuro`.

Comment: i guess your intent is just to initialize the textboxes ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because your are not switching on a single variable, but multiple.

I suspect your motivation to do this, is to make the code more readable ? If this is the case, you could put the common logic of your three if's into a method, to reuse the code and better convey the intent.

Answer (score 2):

**Not Possible**.as `switch` takes `Expression` and executes the matching `Constant Case Label`.

From MSDN :[Switch-Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

> Each case label specifies a constant value. The switch statement 
>   transfers control to
>   the switch section whose case label matches
>   the value of the switch expression

```
Switch(Expression)
{

case constant1://statements
             break;
case constant2://statements
             break;
case constant3://statements
             break;
}
```

if you want to switch with single value then it is possible

```
    int a = 3;    
    if (a == 1)
    {
        //statements
    }
    else if(a == 2)
    {
        //statements
    }
    else if(a == 3)
    {
       //statements
    }
    else if(a == 4)
    {
       //statements
    }
    else
    {
       //statements
    }
```

can be converted into switch as below:

```
int a = 3; 
switch(a)
{
case 1: //statements
break;


case 2: //statements
break;


case 3: //statements
break;


case 4: //statements
break;


default : //statements
break;
}
```